# How to implement a tkinter progress bar in python where the user can pause and restart the progress bar at the same position it was stopped?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

This is the code I have so far, Idealy, I want it to pause until the user clicks start again. Any help is appreciated!!! thanks so much :) <3

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from threading import *
import threading
import _thread

def start():
   w.start()

def stop():
   time.sleep(10)


def stopfunc():
    _thread.start_new_thread(stop,())

window = Tk()

w = ttk.Progressbar(window)
w.pack()
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = 'start', command = start)
button1.pack()
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text = 'stop', command = stopfunc)
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `variable` argument to a control variable such as `IntVar`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def start():
    
   w.start()

def stopfunc():
    w.stop()
    #var.set(var.get())

def reset():
    var.set(0)

window = Tk()

var = IntVar()

w = ttk.Progressbar(window, variable=var)
w.pack()
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = 'start', command = start)
button1.pack()
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text = 'stop', command = stopfunc)
button2.pack()

button2 = ttk.Button(window, text = 'reset', command = reset)
button2.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a way to pause and restart whilst running the progress bar concurrent with a loop:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ttl_ticks = 77  # your countable range
current_tick = 0
pause = True


def start_pause():
    global current_tick
    global pause
    pause = not pause
    while current_tick < ttl_ticks:
        if not pause:
            if current_tick == 0:
                w.start()
            w['value'] = current_tick / ttl_ticks * 100

            w.update()
            w.after(60)

            current_tick += 1
            if current_tick == ttl_ticks:
                w.stop()
                w['value'] = 100
                current_tick = 0
                pause = True
                break
        else:
            w.stop()
            w['value'] = current_tick / ttl_ticks * 100
            break


def reset():
    global current_tick
    global pause
    w.stop()
    pause = True
    current_tick = 0


window = Tk()

w = ttk.Progressbar(window, mode='determinate', length=180)
w.pack()
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text='start / pause', command=start_pause)
button1.pack()
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text='reset', command=reset)
button2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```